# Classes in header files - not able to compile?

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie to c++. I am trying to create header files in c++ to put classes in them and include it in the main fn. Everything works fine when i declare only functions(not class member fns.) in .h file and their definition in a .cpp file of same name. But it gives some error while compiling a project when classes have been defined in the header file! Please help me in solving this problem as I did not find anything useful on the net (google).

Here is my code :

```
// STUDENT.h
#ifndef STUDENT
#define STUDENT

class STUDENT
{
private :
int marks;
public :
void setMarks(int);
void getMarks();
};

#endif
```

//STUDENT.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "STUDENT.h"

void STUDENT :: setMarks(int x)
{
marks = x;
}

void STUDENT :: getMarks()
{
cout << marks;
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "STUDENT.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Additional Details
Errors show on dev c++ :

(3)in file included from main.cpp
(5)an anonymous union can't have fn. members
(11)abstract declarator ' ' used as declaration
(11)namespace-scope anonymous aggregates must be static

P.S I still haven't used objects of class in main. just wanted to test it b4 writing actual program

Comment: Hmm, `class STUDENT`... this should be tagged as homework, right?

Comment: Why don't you put `using namespace std;` in student.cpp?

Comment: i know my actual project is diff. i made this one up just to post on the net.... its like a smaller class but similar to one in my project... and yes i did use namespace in all the files and tried it didnt worked ... finally changed the macro identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem are these two lines:

```
#define STUDENT

class STUDENT
```

The first of those tells the pre-processor to define a *macro* named `STUDENT` and with an empty body. When the pre-processor then sees any mention of `STUDENT` it *replaces* that with the body, in this case nothing (since the macro body is empty).

To solve this, either change the `#define` or change the class name.

Comment: Or, better yet, choose sensible names for both of them, such as `__STUDENT__` for the include guard and `Student` for the class.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Although using double leading underscores might not be a good idea, as the standards (both C and C++ I think) reserves these names for the compiler.

Comment: thank you so much :) it worked ! but i now have smaller problem :( ! when i compile it says 'marks' is undeclared in the getMarks fn.. of STUDENT.cpp file... why ? isn't supp to be like member fns. of a class can access pvt data of the class?

Comment: @PushkarDk If you changed the class name, you remembered to change in not only in the header file but in the source files as well?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That maybe because he is using `cout` in student.cpp but missed to add `using namespace std;`

Comment: oh k thanx so much :) it worked.. compiled well... i have read and understood till files but i hav a few more chaps left and namespaces falls under those chaps... which is why i dont know what are namepaces and why they are used

Answer (score 7):

The preprocessor sees this:

```
#define STUDENT

class STUDENT
{
    …
};
```

The compiler (after preprocessing) sees this:

```
class
{
    …
};
```

Comment: so what should i do to be able to successfully able to compile my program??

Comment: @PushkarDk It should be obvious: You need to make sure to give include guards unique names. They don’t have to be nice, just unique. Something like `YOUR_NAME_HEADER_STUDENT_H` is pretty common. If you want to make *very* sure that it’s unique you can also generate a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID), e.g. `INCLUDE_F80F35D0_DA2F_11E1_9B23_0800200C9A66_H` – but that’s probably paranoia.

Comment: I would alsorecommend you not to use uppercase for symbol names. Uppercase is commonly reserved for preprocessor variables. Name the class simple `Student`

Comment: haha thank you :) this site really rox... so much help from u guys even for a novice like me :p i had earlier posted this on yahoo answers but dint get any response

Answer (score 1):

Rename the header guards as below and you should be ok

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
```